# Wordpress Custom Fields for og:image

Tags: wordpress, metadata, head

I am building a website in Wordpress and I am writing some Articles. When I share my post/article on Facebook, the wrong image appears (on the phone, as on the computer it seems that the image is chosen correctly). I have seen that Facebook needs the og:image tag and it needs to be called in the head metadata. As I do not have many options to add metadata to the page, I felt like using the **Custom Fileds** in Wordpress as being the cleanest way. As I am new to this and I am not sure I did it correctly, please guide me on how to call these custom fileds to the head metadata part of my page when it loads. I have attached a snip of my custom field here:
[custom custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPGS4.jpg)

Please let me know if my thinking was correct or if I should use another method to accomplish this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually, an SEO plugin is used for this. You should try `yoast` or `All in One SEO Pack`.

Comment: Is there a way to use SNIPPETS plugin to call for the certain Custom Fields to be placed in the head of the page? I am quite weak at php / functions. I am just saying this as it seems overkill to add another plugin for a line in each page. Thank you.